# Stylesheet for QLineEdit to show without editor area

Tags: qt

How to tune QLineEdit view to:

1. show as label with transparent background for displaying mode.
2. show as common QLineEdit widget when user clicks on it to editing.

Comment: maybe you might switch it with QLabel

Comment: I thought about the option to show QLineEdit above QLabel when user clicks on label, and hide editor when text is entered. But if this can be implemented by single widget it will be more properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this css to apply `QLabel`-like style when it is not in edit mode:

```
QLineEdit:!focus
{
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background: transparent;
}
QLineEdit:focus
{
  background: white;
}
```